# Sortable not working AngularJS / UI

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-sortable

I'm trying to get my list sortable with AngularUI

plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/2zbn2rBpnat8lEQZRGd9?p=preview

```
<ul ui-sortable ng-model="deals.numer">
            <li ng-repeat="deals in list" class="bg-info" style="padding: 5px; margin: 5px;">
```

is it possible to make this list sortable after adding few new elements to array?

Comment: Firstly, you have to add `'ui.sortable'` as a module dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make you plunker work:

- Add jquery and jqueryUI as a dependency
- Add `ui.sortable` as a module dependency:

  ```
  angular.module('myApp', ['ui.sortable']);
  ```
- Replace:

  ```
  <ul ui-sortable ng-model="deals.numer">
  ```

  with:

  ```
  <ul ui-sortable ng-model="list">
  ```

---

See **[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UrSPirdL9G64d57yI1RQ?p=preview)**